# Selenium Web Driver : How to print the contents in the Onmouseover event?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am finding difficulty to fetch the contents in the OnMouseover event. Can anyone please help me out.

```
<HTML><TR>
  <TD id="Lending Operations Manager BFS " class=profileInnerTable>
   <A style="CURSOR: hand" id=rolename1 class=TabLink onmouseover="ddrivetip1('Enables a team manager to view.','lightyellow',250)" onmouseout=hideddrivetip() ;>Lending Operations Manager BFS </A>
   <IMG align=bottom src="http://10.26.210.74:9080/cbaUserAdmin/images/clock.JPG">
 </TD>
</TR>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure the java implementation, but in python it would be

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr td.profileInnerTable a#rolename1").get_attribute("onmouseover")`

which would return:

```
ddrivetip1('Enables a team manager to view.','lightyellow',250)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used getattribute function in JAVA and spilt the returned value which i can verify for my expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a hover action to get the onMouseOver activated, if that is what you mean by `"fetch the contents"`

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action hoverAction = builder.moveToElement(rolename1).build();
hoverAction.perform();
driver.findElement(By.id("rolename1")).click();
```

But without knowing what the `ddrivetip1` javascript function does it is hard to tell.

Alternatively you can just execute the javascript:

```
driver.executeScript("ddrivetip1('Enables a team manager to view.','lightyellow',250);");
```